# save as PDF produces blank pages in MS Office Powerpoint

Tags: windows-xp, pdf, microsoft-powerpoint

I am using Microsoft PowerPoint to save a file as a PDF. Two weeks ago this stopped working properly. The generated PDF has the proper slide format but contains no content.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which version of Powerpoint?

Comment: How are you saving as PDF? print to pdf?

Comment: which app?? pdfcreator??

Comment: I will mirror the above comments. Explaining how you used to do something that works and how you are doing it now will help us troubleshoot for you. Additionally, anything that's changed (method, programs, etc) will also help